# Filter out columns containing specific word

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the pandas DataFrame I need to filter out those columns that contain the word 'fixed'. Then I want to create another DataFrame with only those columns. How can I do this?

```
cols = dataset.columns

split = lambda x: [c for c in x.split('_') if c.startswith('fixed')]
```

Comment: Don't use `split = lambda...`.  `lambda` functions are unnamed, so don't give a name to them.  It is against PEP 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`.ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) attribute:

```
fixed = [c for c in dataset.columns if c.startswith("fixed")]
fixed_dataset = dataset.ix[:, fixed]
```

Similarly for the opposite case:

```
non_fixed = [c for c in dataset.columns if not c.startswith("fixed")]
dataset.ix[:, non_fixed]
```